# Clock Switching on PIC24

Tags: microchip, pic-ccs

I am running a PIC24F32KA302 using the Low Power RC with Postscaler (FRCDIV) clock source at 250 KHz.  I would like to switch the clock in the code to 8 MHz FRC Oscillator with Postscaler and PLL module (FRCPLL).  I am using the CCS PIC-C compiler.  My code to perform clock switching:

```
void oscillator_16Mhz()
{
    disable_interrupts(GLOBAL);

    #asm
      MOV #0x742,W1        // OSCONH
      MOV #0x78,W2
      MOV #0x9A,W3
      MOV #0x01,WREG
      MOV.b W2,[W1]
      MOV.b W3,[W1]
      MOV.b WREG,OSCONH
      MOV #0x743,W1        // OSCONH
      MOV #0x46,W2
      MOV #0x57,W3
      MOV.b W2,[W1]
      MOV.b W3,[W1]
      BSET OSCON,#0
    #endasm

    delay_ms(200);

//  #use delay(internal=16MHz)   // For wifi Interface
    enable_interrupts(GLOBAL);
}
```

The dissasmbler listing:

```
98:                void oscillator_16Mhz()
99: 
               {
100:                disable_interrupts(GLOBAL);
  0EC6  A9E081     bclr.b 0x0081,#7
  0EC8  200E04     mov.w #0xe0,0x0008
  0ECA  880214     mov.w 0x0008,0x0042
  0ECC  A8E081     bset.b 0x0081,#7

101:                #asm

102:                MOV #0x742,W1  //OSCONH
  0ECE  207421     mov.w #0x742,0x0002

103:                MOV #0x78,W2
  0ED0  200782     mov.w #0x78,0x0004

104:                MOV #0x9A,W3
  0ED2  2009A3     mov.w #0x9a,0x0006

105:                MOV #0x01,WREG
  0ED4  200010     mov.w #0x1,0x0000

106:                MOV.b W2,[W1]
  0ED6  784882     mov.b 0x0004,[0x0002]

107:                MOV.b W3,[W1]
  0ED8  784883     mov.b 0x0006,[0x0002]

108:                MOV.b WREG,OSCONH
  0EDA  B7E742     mov.b 0x0000,0x0742

109:                MOV #0x743,W1  //OSCONH
  0EDC  207431     mov.w #0x743,0x0002

110:                MOV #0x46,W2
  0EDE  200462     mov.w #0x46,0x0004

111:                MOV #0x57,W3
  0EE0  200573     mov.w #0x57,0x0006

112:                MOV.b W2,[W1]
  0EE2  784882     mov.b 0x0004,[0x0002]

113:                MOV.b W3,[W1]
  0EE4  784883     mov.b 0x0006,[0x0002]

114:                BSET OSCON,#0
  0EE6  A80742     bset.b 0x0742,#0

115:                #endasm

116:                delay_ms(200);
  0EE8  090BB6     repeat #2998
  0EEA  000000     nop

117:                
118:               //   #use delay(internal=16MHz)//For wifi Interface

119:                enable_interrupts(GLOBAL);
  0EEC  A9E081     bclr.b 0x0081,#7
  0EEE  EF2042     clr.w 0x0042
  0EF0  A8E081     bset.b 0x0081,#7
  0EF2  060000     return

120:               }
```

I can set up the oscillator to run at the desired frequency in the code at the start of the program, and both frequencies work.  I am unable to switch between clocks.  The clock frequency does not change when I run this routine.

oIf anyone has any experience with clock switching on these parts, I certainly appreciate help

Comment: My first idea would be: you want to switch between the PLL and non-PLL versions of the same clock source, and this may not be directly supported (the PLL is normally off, after turning it on, it has to stabilize). I would try switching first to LPRC, and then to the PLL'd FRC. Also, read section 9.2.1 in the data sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for anyone who was looking to help.

As I mentioned, I am using the PICC compiler from CCS on this project.  I should have known.  Their built-in-function "setup_oscillator" handles all of the unlocking and clock switching code.  Very nice compiler.

I tried the code using the XC compiler from Microchip using the suggestion of @Laszlo Valko and it works, so I must have had a problem in my ASM syntax in PICC.  I did not try switching directly from LPRC to FRCPLL.

Comment: That's the very reason I have never used CCS's compiler: unless you check the code generated, you may never know what magic happens in the background - in the end, that's simply just more work.